# Change label on form label via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched for jquery change the labels although there were a lot of answers they didn't pertain to my question. I want to change the label to something else that includes links. I can't seem to get it to work!! I've put the JS in the head position of the code but had no luck and even used JSFiddle please see below. What am I doing wrong?

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/14tx86j5/

**HTML**

```
    <input name="input_147.1" value="I agree to Veryappt’s Terms of Service" id="choice_3_147_1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="choice_3_147_1" id="label_3_147_1">I agree to Companies Terms of Service</label>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $("#label_3_147_1 label").html('You also agree to our <a href="http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS" name="terms" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>, which describes how we process your information. <a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1733224?hl=en-GB" name="terms" target="_blank">Learn More</a> about why we ask for this information.');

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: u need to include jquery liberary https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js

Comment: Two elements with the same ID will always give you these errors

Comment: Apart from the answer which is now posted, I wonder why you would do this thing?
Can't you just modify the html? :P

Comment: Why would I need 1.12.3 wouldn't the latest google version allow me to do it? 

Ok so I need to remove the duplicate IDs...

Gravity Forms as they don't allow HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong Selector to target label element. The selector you have used looks for label element inside element with id `label_3_147_1`. You need to use:

```
$("#label_3_147_1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me . 
**You need to include JS Libraries**

```
   $('#label_3_147_1').html('You also agree to our <a href="http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS" name="terms" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>, which describes how we process your information. <a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1733224?hl=en-GB" name="terms" target="_blank">Learn More</a> about why we ask for this information.');

   });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/14tx86j5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only id of label something like that:

$("#label_3_147_1").html('Put Your html here');